# How to letterbox SpriteKit games for iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I have a game developed in `SpriteKit`. Currently the game covers the whole screen on iPhone X.

I want to letterbox it so there is black space at top and bottom when in portrait mode, and at left, right and bottom when in landscape mode. Basically, I want the game to be contained within the **safe area**.

What is the recommended, most straight forward approach to achieve this?

Comment: just make sure the SKView is confined to the safe area

Comment: you should not letterbox an app on iPhone X, see [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/).

Comment: @holex yes I know that, this is just a temporary solution until designs are updated.

Comment: in that case, if you app does not target iOS11 the letterboxing happens automatically by iOS anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am overriding `viewWillLayoutSubviews` in my `ViewController`. This works at the moment, but I am not sure if this is the right approach. Feedback will be appreciated.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if let window = view.window {
            view.frame = window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is for the oldschools using Obj-C

```
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
UIWindow *window = [self.view window];
skView.frame = window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame; 
SKScene * scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.frame.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```